# Can I add a Google App Script file to all spreadsheets in a folder?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api

I need to add a Google App Script (my code.gs file that contains more than one function) to all the spreadsheets in a folder (there are about 100). Is there a way to automate this in Google Drive or Google Cloud Console or do I need to go into each file individually and paste the code?

I tried searching Google and ended up asking ChatGPT. It told me to select all the sheets in the folder, go to More Actions (three dots) and select Google App Script, but there is no "Google App Script" in the More options menu so I'm very confused.

Thank you

Comment: Related question: [Remotely update Sheets on client-side with new Library version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55421309/1330560); dated 2019. Giveaway: `You'll have to do it yourself.`